# Scripts only working on home page

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am using the following example code to enqueue several scripts..

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
    function my_scripts() { 
         wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery-Main', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.js',array(),'2.0.3', true);
    }
```

If I set the `$in_footer` parameter to true, the scripts load in the footer and work correctly **only on the homepage**.

If I leave the `$in_footer` parameter blank, the scripts work correctly on all pages **except the homepage.**

This problem only started occurring recently and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Is there a `wp_footer()` call in all your footer template files?

Comment: Please define "work". So you mean it is loaded, or that it does its functionality?

Comment: yes wp_footer() is called correctly, and by 'work' I mean functions.